# Babel spanish option and fancyvrb incompatibility

Tags: babel, incompatibility, fancyvrb, spanish

The following MWE compiles without problems

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\SaveVerb{x>y}|x > y|

\begin{equation*}
\UseVerb{x>y}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

but if I replace the option `english` by `spanish` in babel, I got the following error:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.10 \UseVerb{x>y}
```

I can fix the issue removing `>` from the name used in the `\SaveVerb` macro, that is, `\SaveVerb{xy}|x > y|`, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `spanish` for `babel` makes `<` `>` active characters; you can use the `es-noquoting` option:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
```

as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\SaveVerb{x>y}|x > y|

\begin{equation*}
\UseVerb{x>y}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

but then you loose the automatic quotation features implemented by the module through those characters (though the `quotating` environment can still be used); another option would be to locally deactivate these features and then restore them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\deactivatequoting
\SaveVerb{x>y}|x > y|

\begin{equation*}
\UseVerb{x>y}
\end{equation*}
\activatequoting
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AndrésSicard-Ramírez You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the commands to sanitize their argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\let\xSaveVerb\SaveVerb
\def\SaveVerb#1{\xSaveVerb{\detokenize{#1}}}
\let\xUseVerb\UseVerb
\def\UseVerb#1{\xUseVerb{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\SaveVerb{x>y}|x > y|

\begin{equation*}
\UseVerb{x>y}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```